# How to search on MySQL Pivot Tables without using Views

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, view, case

Imagine two simple pivot tables `a` and `v` with the following structure and data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a` (
  `i` bigint(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` bigint(13) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`i`),
  KEY `a` (`a`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
COMMENT='records' AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `a` (`i`, `a`) VALUES
(1, 0),
(2, 1),
(3, 2),
(4, 2),
(5, 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `v` (
  `i` bigint(13) NOT NULL,
  `k` bigint(13) NOT NULL,
  `v` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ixk` (`i`,`k`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 
COMMENT='varchar (1024) fields';

INSERT INTO `v` (`i`, `k`, `v`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Organizations'),
(3, 1, 'Apple Inc.'),
(3, 2, 'apple.com'),
(4, 1, 'Microsoft Corporation'),
(4, 2, 'microsoft.com'),
(5, 1, 'Google Corporation'),
(5, 2, 'google.com');
```

One could extract two "virtual" tables of information from these tables as follows, using pivot table select statements:

```
select a.i as 'id',
ifnull (max(case when v.k = 1 then v.v end),'') 'Table'
from a
left join v on a.i = v.i
where a.a = 0
group by a.i
```

yielding the following:

```
+----+---------------+
| id | Table         |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Organizations |
+----+---------------+
```

and

```
select a.i as 'id',
ifnull (max(case when v.k = 1 then v.v end),'') 'Company',
ifnull (max(case when v.k = 2 then v.v end),'') 'Domain'
from a 
left join v on a.i = v.i 
where a.a = 2 group by a.i
```

yielding:

```
+----+-----------------------+---------------+
| id | Company               | Domain        |
+----+-----------------------+---------------+
|  3 | Apple Inc.            | apple.com     |
|  4 | Microsoft Corporation | microsoft.com |
|  5 | Google Corporation    | google.com    |
+----+-----------------------+---------------+
```

One could then create a view of say the last query:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED VIEW  `organizations` 
AS SELECT a.i AS  'id', 
IFNULL( MAX( CASE WHEN v.k =1 THEN v.v END ) ,  '' )  'Company', 
IFNULL( MAX( CASE WHEN v.k =2 THEN v.v END ) ,  '' )  'Domain'
FROM a
LEFT JOIN v ON a.i = v.i
WHERE a.a =2
GROUP BY a.i
```

and then perform searches like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `organizations` 
WHERE  `Company` LIKE  '%Apple%'
```

to extract data:

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | Company    | Domain    |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  3 | Apple Inc. | apple.com |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

How could this identical search be performed on the pivot tables, without using a view (just using tables `a` and `v`)?

I have tried a case statement in the where clause:

```
select a.i as 'id',
ifnull (max(case when v.k = 1 then v.v end),'') 'Company',
ifnull (max(case when v.k = 2 then v.v end),'') 'Domain'
from a 
left join v on a.i = v.i 
where a.a = 2
AND CASE WHEN v.k = 1 THEN v.v LIKE  '%Apple%' ELSE TRUE END
group by a.i
```

but it does not isolate/extract the virtual row, it displays all the rows but with only the matching data:

```
+----+------------+---------------+
| id | Company    | Domain        |
+----+------------+---------------+
|  3 | Apple Inc. | apple.com     |
|  4 |            | microsoft.com |
|  5 |            | google.com    |
+----+------------+---------------+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   select a.i as 'id',
     ifnull (max(case when v.k = 1 then v.v end),'') 'Company',
     ifnull (max(case when v.k = 2 then v.v end),'') 'Domain'
   from a 
   left join v on a.i = v.i 
   WHERE a.a =2
   group by a.i
) AS sub
WHERE `Company` LIKE  '%Apple%'
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b8ea3/3/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═════════════╦═══════════╗
║ id  ║  Company    ║  Domain   ║
╠═════╬═════════════╬═══════════╣
║  3  ║ Apple Inc.  ║ apple.com ║
╚═════╩═════════════╩═══════════╝
```